# Current USB Device Power Draw

Tags: macos, usb, iokit

I am writing a USB driver and have a popup that contains specific information about the currently selected USB device.

However, I seem unable to find any way to determine the current power being used by the device. I can obtain the current power available on the port, but not the device itself.

There are API's to request extra power and to release it, but I can find nothing that tells me what the current power draw of the device is.

I know it is possible as other utilities can show this information, however, IOKit seems to lack the usual level of Apple documentation!

Comment: Unless there is an actual way to read the actual power consumption of a USB device the best solution I found was to read the MaxPower field of the IOUSBConfigurationDescriptor struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the "Requested Power" property on the `IOUSBDevice` node corresponding to the device of use to you? This is the value of the "bMaxPower" property in the configuration descriptor, i.e. the device's advertised maximum power consumption in 2mA units. Things get a little more complicated with USB3, the extra 400mA that can be made available to a superspeed device are recorded separately, and I think it's different again for the extra power supplied to iPods, iPhones, etc. which don't follow the USB3 spec. You'll need to check the IOUSBDevice source code for that, and maybe do some digging around with IORegistryExplorer.

Comment: Yes, I am now using the bMaxPower field, and am adding the 'extra' power requested as well, which for my use will probably always be zero, but never hurts to be sure. Thanks for your answer! :)